# Excel - Formula / Macro to auto increment values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to auto-increment a value by 1 each time the name column matches the same value.

What's the best way to output the below in excel - i.e. via formula or macro?

I have tried to use an excel IF formula but can't seem to get it work quite right!

Many Thanks in advance

| Name | Reference | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1234 | N/A |
| First | 1256 | 1234.1 |
| First | 12567 | 1234.2 |
| Second | 666 | N/A |
| Third | 4321 | N/A |
| Third | 43211 | 4321.1 |
| Third | 43212 | 4321.2 |
| Third | 43213 | 4321.3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with excel formula like

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1,NA(),VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$B2,2,FALSE)&"."&COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)-1)
```

**Edit as per comment below - New formula**

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1,NA(),VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$B2,2,FALSE)&"."&REPT("0",3-LEN(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)-1))&COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)-1)
```

3 in `REPT("0",3` can be adjusted to increase or decrease the number of digits.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks Naresh. Is there any way that the .1 can be .001, .002 etc.?

Comment: Is there any way that the .1 can be .001, .002 etc.?

Comment: @RyanJackson Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA:

```vb
Sub mysub()
    Dim oCurrentCell As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oLastCell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    [c2] = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'Treat first cell independently to avoid error on offset(-1)
    
    For Each oCurrentCell In Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
    
        For Each oCell In Range("A2", oCurrentCell.Offset(-1))
            'For each cell above the current one
            If oCell = oCurrentCell Then
                Set oLastCell = oCell
            End If
        Next oCell
        
        If oLastCell Is Nothing Then
            oCurrentCell.Offset(, 2) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Else
            'If a cell of equal value has been found
            If IsError(oLastCell.Offset(, 2)) Then
                oCurrentCell.Offset(, 2) = oLastCell.Offset(, 1) + 0.1
            Else
                oCurrentCell.Offset(, 2) = oLastCell.Offset(, 2) + 0.1
            End If
            
            Set oLastCell = Nothing
        End If
    Next oCurrentCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oCurrentCell = Nothing
    Set oLastCell = Nothing
End Sub
```